# I want to know what happened when I use the command "g++ -o main main.o -L<directory> -l<lib_name>"

Tags: linker, g++, linker-flags

Supposing I have **main.c main.o libheymath.so** in current directory. I want to link them together to generate an executable file. I use command **"g++ -o main main.o -L./ -lheymath"** to realize that. But I don't know why I should indicate the library directory and name. As far as I know, when I run **"./main"** the system will load the shared library into memory in specific directories such as **/lib** and **/use/lib** and directories specified in LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc. but not what I have indicated. So what's the purpose of **"-L./ -lheymath"**?

> working directory files:
>
> > main.c,  main.o, libheymath.so
>
> command:
>
> > g++ -o main main.o -L./ -lheymath
> >
> > ./main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-L allows to indicates a path where to look to find lib(s) at link time (it is not 'saved' in the produced executable to be reused when you will launch the executable)

-l indicates a lib you want to link with, this allows to check if some symbols are missing or not and to know the list of libs to load when you will launch the executable.

When you link the path of these libs is not saved into the executable because both executable and libs can be moved after the link (and may be installed on an other host)

Note `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is used when you start an executable to find the dynamic libs, it is not used when you link objects/libs to make an executable

Comment: In addition to checking symbols, Is there any other things to check?

Comment: @009 If I am not wrong no, except the possible management of the templates definitions to generate/keep but this is not really at 'link' step. Note the name of the symbol associated to a method also contains the profile of the method (return type and args type)